# is it possible to add a GestureRecognizer to a label in a custom UIView subview

Tags: ios, uiview, uilabel, uigesturerecognizer

I am refactoring a `ViewController` that I have adopted and is creating `UIView`s in the controller code. I'd like to move it to a custom `UIView` but would like to handle the Gesture Recognizer in the controller.

I have an `ItemViewController` which has a custom `UIView`. Within the `ItemController`, I'd like to do something like:

```
ItemView *itemView = [[ItemView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(30.0f,_runningYPosition,100.0f, 50.0f)];
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapRecognizer2 = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapRecognized:)];
itemView.miHeaderLabel.tag = [item itemID];
[itemView.miHeaderLabel addGestureRecognizer: tapRecognizer2];
```

that references

```
- (void)tapRecognized:(id)sender
{
    ...
}
```

in `ItemViewController` (NOT in the custom view).

But it doesn't seem to work. Is it possible to add a GestureRecognizer to a label that is a property of a subview in a ViewController? Anything obvious I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `userInteractionEnabled` to `YES` on the label for it to accept touches (and therefore for the gesture to receive touches).

Comment: thx Wain, would I need to set that in the controller or the custom view? or would it not matter?

Comment: I'd set it in the view when the label is created.